# How to create a JSON file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

This question is very similar to some I have read here, but I still haven't found an answer that would solve my problem.

I am creating a basic quiz in Javascript, and one of the tasks I was given is this (given to do as an exercise):

> Store the quiz questions in an external JSON file.

I can go with local storage, but it is not saving it to a file. Can it be done in Javascript (without JQuery, without Node)?

Comment: you will need to use node to store in a file JSON.stringify() is the function you need .

Comment: I know about JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(),  but I don`t know how to stringify it to a different local file. So, no way from pure Javascript?

Comment: Might also consider cloud data storage

Comment: Are you sure the exercise isn't  to read the quiz questions from a JSON file where they have been stored, as opposed to hard coding them in JavaScript?

Comment: It says "Store the quiz questions in an external JSON file". So, I guess I have to save(store) them to a different file, because they were already made in javascript. That is how I interpretated the exercise.